# Docker run Ubuntu does not work

Tags: docker

I am trying to start an Ubuntu container on an Ubuntu VM, and everytime I start it, it says

```
dgr@irpsim:~$ docker run ubuntu
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for ubuntu:latest not found.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The same happens for `ubuntu:20.04` or other versions. The same command is printed in many documentations and also works on my local machine, so I assume, this is some configuration issue of the VM. Strangely, `docker run -it fedora` works, other containers like `openjdk:latest` can also be downloaded.

Is there some good point to start debugging this issue?

**EDIT**: Looking deeper at the issue, it might have happened that `yes | docker image prune --all --filter "until=4320h"` have removed the image. Is there some way to get it again?

**EDIT 2**: This seems to affect all the images that were never used on the system. If I download old images, everything older than 17.10 can be downloaded:

```
docker pull -a ubuntu
10.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists 
86b54f4b6a4e: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:f6695b2d24dd2e1da0a79fa72459e33505da79939c13ce50e90675c32988ab64
12.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
d8868e50ac4c: Pull complete 
83251ac64627: Pull complete 
589bba2f1b36: Pull complete 
d62ecaceda39: Pull complete 
6d93b41cfc6b: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:18305429afa14ea462f810146ba44d4363ae76e4c8dfc38288cf73aa07485005
12.04.5: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:18305429afa14ea462f810146ba44d4363ae76e4c8dfc38288cf73aa07485005
12.10: Pulling from library/ubuntu
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists 
b3d68acd1381: Pull complete 
6b4d7481ec7a: Pull complete 
6256ff031770: Pull complete 
1a0d911d83d1: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:002fba3e3255af10be97ea26e476692a7ebed0bb074a9ab960b2e7a1526b15d7
13.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists 
727520c5e30b: Pull complete 
2e8f7add78f9: Pull complete 
4600be257a84: Pull complete 
89d0f0874176: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:bc48dd7075ce920ebbaa4581d3200e9fb3aaec31591061d7e3a280a04ef0248c
13.10: Pulling from library/ubuntu
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists 
0d8710fc57fd: Pull complete 
5037c5cd623d: Pull complete 
83b53423b49f: Pull complete 
e9e8bd3b94ab: Pull complete 
7db00e6b6e5e: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:403105e61e2d540187da20d837b6a6e92efc3eb4337da9c04c191fb5e28c44dc
14.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
2e6e20c8e2e6: Pull complete 
0551a797c01d: Pull complete 
512123a864da: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:64483f3496c1373bfd55348e88694d1c4d0c9b660dee6bfef5e12f43b9933b30
14.04.1: Pulling from library/ubuntu
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
76a4cab4eb20: Pull complete 
d2ff49536f4d: Pull complete 
f94adccdbb9c: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2eb231f768446001a7cf9024ec9724cec23f6768e9ccb4e61499718d34621fbe
14.04.2: Pulling from library/ubuntu
f25e451100bc: Pull complete 
2dbe4abf311d: Pull complete 
7ae2bc99836a: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:a1cec70421f71f00c8bdb0adf0226dc548ff5ba9699cbd5fa09acdb68df82a02
14.04.3: Pulling from library/ubuntu
8387d9ff0016: Pull complete 
3b52deaaf0ed: Pull complete 
4bd501fad6de: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2febbcede4f3eb82ae0dc44518a2e2a7b06a0452685e64e6b13f51b278294780
14.04.4: Pulling from library/ubuntu
96c6a1f3c3b0: Pull complete 
ed40d4bcb313: Pull complete 
b171f9dbc13b: Pull complete 
ccfc4df4fbba: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:9274d908eb6d9a3784e93290fcc49f3c5618db9e1b0174ee27f9fc75aa3c0fb0
14.04.5: Pulling from library/ubuntu
1d8592394ba1: Pull complete 
01aa7f61ccd1: Pull complete 
5dd2552a960e: Pull complete 
7cbe941c5e3e: Pull complete 
2549ecfb14c6: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:30204139c6ab96ebd75d72f34db390f28c4decd5e563488b4e485bf979397b67
14.10: Pulling from library/ubuntu
b0efe5c05b4c: Pull complete 
0a1f1b169319: Pull complete 
1ceb0a3c7c48: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6341c688b4b0b82ec735389b3c97df8cf2831b8cb8bd1856779130a86574ac5c
15.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
9502adfba7f1: Pull complete 
4332ffb06e4b: Pull complete 
2f937cc07b5f: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2fb27e433b3ecccea2a14e794875b086711f5d49953ef173d8a03e8707f1510f
15.10: Pulling from library/ubuntu
7dcf5a444392: Pull complete 
759aa75f3cee: Pull complete 
3fa871dc8a2b: Pull complete 
224c42ae46e7: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:02521a2d079595241c6793b2044f02eecf294034f31d6e235ac4b2b54ffc41f3
16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
58690f9b18fc: Pull complete 
b51569e7c507: Pull complete 
da8ef40b9eca: Pull complete 
fb15d46c38dc: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:1f1a2d56de1d604801a9671f301190704c25d604a416f59e03c04f5c6ffee0d6
16.10: Pulling from library/ubuntu
dca7be20e546: Pull complete 
40bca54f5968: Pull complete 
61464f23390e: Pull complete 
d99f0bcd5dc8: Pull complete 
120db6f90955: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:8dc9652808dc091400d7d5983949043a9f9c7132b15c14814275d25f94bca18a
17.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
c2ca09a1934b: Pull complete 
d6c3619d2153: Pull complete 
0efe07335a04: Pull complete 
6b1bb01b3a3b: Pull complete 
43a98c187399: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:5d41c289942008211c2964bca72800f5c9d5ea5aa4057528da617fb36463d4ab
17.10: Pulling from library/ubuntu
4ccdce43d1e0: Pull complete 
c95f13c88d92: Pull complete 
82656eee95ad: Pull complete 
78ff727be57a: Pull complete 
448bb314afa5: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:3b811ac794645dfaa47408f4333ac6e433858ff16908965c68f63d5d315acf94
manifest for ubuntu not found
```

Unfortunately, knowing this, I still have no clue why these images cannot be downloaded and how to fix this.

Comment: Log in to the Docker site and try again

Comment: What do you mean by log in? I'm just executing `docker run` on the command line, I'm not logged in to any docker site.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Docker should automatically fetch the images again. Can you run another container, like `docker run hello-world`?

Comment: Yes, also hello-world works. Its just the ubuntu container thats missing.

Comment: does `docker pull ubuntu` work? does it work for any other container that is not locally stored? this might be a connectivity / DNS Issue?

Comment: No, `docker pull ubuntu` does not work (same error as above), `docker pull fedora:35` did work and download an image, so I assume its not about the network. `docker pull debian` also works, so I assume it is some issue with the ubuntu image. Maybe it has been deleted by docker prune. Additionally, there are still running containers using the ubuntu image (probably in old versions).

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-install docker and make sure the docker version is the latest.
For me, it worked upgrading from 18.03 to 23.01.

Comment: Do you any supporting info or a link I can look at that says I would need to reinstall?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, we have some container that we cannot move so easily, and therefore, setting up docker completely fresh is not an option. We are on docker 17.05.0-ce, which is the default for our Ubuntu installation.